Number of ways of colouring 7 points of an hexagon satisfying some conditions
Question
Let $ABCDEF$ be a regular hexagon and let point $O$ be its centre. How many ways can you colour these seven points either red or blue such that there doesn't exist any equilateral triangle with vertices of all the same colour $?$
My approach
There are 8 equilateral triangles which can be formed. I tried using the inclusion-exclusion principle, that is
Total number of ways - (1 triangle is coloured equilateral) +(2 triangles are coloured equilateral)..
But I'm not getting the correct answer by this. Could anyone help? Also please provide more efficient ways to do this.
For context, this is a beginner high school problem.
Edit:
With the help of @CalvinLin, I tried again with 8, but still getting incorrect answer.

Note that BDF, ACE are also equilateral triangles. That greatly restricts the possibilities. $\quad$ Hint: WLOG $O$ and $A$ are red (why?).

Edited, and what does wlog stand for?

Without Loss Of Generality.

Having all the outer vertices the same colour is prohibited, so some outer vertex must be the same colour as $O$ , and that determines the colours of all the other vertices

How did you get $8$ from @CalvinLin's comment? That is indeed incorrect.

6 small triangles and 2 ACE and BDF @Henry

@CalvinLin so, if we assume O and A to be red, then B and F have to be blue,  D has to be red, C and E to be blue, so I'm now getting 12 (6 vertices ×2 ) as we fixed O and A, that's still incoreect

I agree that there are 8 equilateral triangles. Henry is asking how did you get that there are 8 (or 12) ways to color these 7 points. Can you list out (say) 3 or 4 of the ways? $\quad$ FWIW It seems to me that you're on the right track, but you are confusing yourself / not thinking clearly. EG What does "6 vertices * 2 " mean?

@CalvinLin we initially assumed A and O to be red. Like that, we could have assumed O and B, O and C (like that 6), and we could have assumed them to be red or blue(like that 2), is that not correct?

Close!  Is "O and A are red" a distinct coloring from "O and D are red"? In each case, which vertices are red? $\quad$ Repeat this for other pairs of "6 vertices", to ensure that you have distinct colorings.

But the answer is 20, it is more than 12, if I eliminate some cases, I will get less than 12@CalvinLin

Then you have to choose what to trust: 20 or logic.

Following Calvin Lin's comments, you have said

so, if we assume O and A to be red, then B and F have to be blue, D has to be red, C and E to be blue

which is essentially this diagram:

which, since the large equilateral triangles stop you having the colours of all the outer points differing from the central point, gives you the pattern that three points on one diagonal must be the same colour as the central point  and the other four points the other colour.
More generally any of the three diagonals could be the same colour, and that colour could be red or blue, so there are $6$ possibilities in total:


I think there may be $36$ possibilities if you forget the large equilateral triangles.
